# Getting clientBundleFieldNameUnlikelyToCollideWithUserSpecifiedFieldOkay is not a function

Tags: firefox, gwt

I am getting the following exception:

```
Caused by: com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (TypeError) : $tmp_0_g$.get_clientBundleFieldNameUnlikelyToCollideWithUserSpecifiedFieldOkay_28_g$(...).style_129_g$ is not a function
    at Unknown.fBj_g$(BillingOverviewView_BinderImpl.java:75)
    at Unknown.KPi_g$(BillingOverviewView_BinderImpl.java:43)
    at Unknown.GPi_g$(BillingOverviewView_BinderImpl.java:31)
    at Unknown.HPi_g$(BillingOverviewView_BinderImpl.java:28)
    at Unknown.APi_g$(BillingOverviewView.java:34)
```

but only in Firefox. It's working without any troubles in Chrome.

This is the view that's being mentioned in the stacktrace:

```java
class BillingOverviewView extends ViewWithUiHandlers<BillingOverviewUiHandlers> implements BillingOverviewPresenter.MyView {

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private final static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(BillingOverviewView.class.getName());

    interface Binder extends UiBinder<Widget, BillingOverviewView> {
    }

    @UiField MaterialRow rowShops;

    @Inject
    BillingOverviewView(Binder uiBinder) {
        this.initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
    }

    @Override
    public void clearShopCards() {
        this.rowShops.clear();
    }

    @Override
    public void addShopCard(MyView view) {
        MaterialColumn colShop = new MaterialColumn(12, 12, 12);
        colShop.add(view);
        this.rowShops.add(colShop);
    }

}
```

Any idea where this is coming from and why I get this only in Firefox?

The only place where I'm actually manipulating IDs is here:

```java
@Inject
PaymentMethodTabView(Binder uiBinder) {

    String id = HTMLPanel.createUniqueId();

    this.btnPaymentMethod = new MaterialButton();
    this.btnPaymentMethod.setText("PM");
    this.btnPaymentMethod.setActivates(id);

    this.dpPaymentMethod = new MaterialDropDown(id);
    this.dpPaymentMethod.setConstrainWidth(false);

    this.dpPaymentMethod.addSelectionHandler(new SelectionHandler<Widget>() {
        @Override
        public void onSelection(SelectionEvent<Widget> event) {
            if(!(event.getSelectedItem() instanceof CreditCardDropDownItem)) {
                return;
            }
            CreditCardDropDownItem item = ((CreditCardDropDownItem)event.getSelectedItem());
            CreditCard creditCard = PaymentMethodTabView.this.tokenToCreditCard.get(item.getToken());
            PaymentMethodTabView.this.onSelection(creditCard);
        }
    });

    this.initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));

    this.creditCardContainer.setWidget(this.creditCardWidget);
}
```

but as you can see I'm using `HTMLPanel.createUniqueId()` to make sure I got unique IDs.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `gss="true"` to this:

```xml
<ui:style gss="true">

.shop-panel {
    margin: 30px;
    padding: 30px;

    border-style: solid;
    border-right: 0;
    border-left: 0;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #AAAAAA;
}

.main-content {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}

</ui:style>
```

Did the trick.